# Resize image column

Tags: html, css

i been checking some tutorials and stackoverflow posts put i cant put my image in the right column resizing.

I have a left and right column, where in the left is located the menu and right the some content and background image that resizes. But for some reason the background image doesnt float to the right.

The link:
http://jsfiddle.net/47abrtry/

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper .left-content{
    float:left;
    width: 256px;

}
.wrapper .right-content{
    width: auto;
    float:left;
}
.wrapper .right-content .slider-bg img{
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't float the right box, just set there left margin.

```
.wrapper .right-content{
    margin: 0 0 0 256px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47abrtry/1/

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i was looking for, but is it possible to limit the width of the image?

Comment: Got it, to limit width of the image just use "min-width", thanks.